# VB.NET handling mutiple form by one method

Tags: vb.net, winforms

NET

I feel I am building too many similar methods. However, I am not sure how to  minimize number of similar methods.

I implemented similar methods for each form's event. Each method is doing almost same task however, each method handle different form's event

for example, I have one class to handle form event and two form.

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim IFL As New InterfaceLoader
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        IFL.Change_Label(Me)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class Form2

    Dim IFL As New InterfaceLoader
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        IFL.Change_Label(Me)
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class InterfaceLoader

    Public Sub Change_Label(Nameofform As Form1)
        Nameofform.Label1.Text = "Hey This is Form !!"
    End Sub

    Public Sub Change_Label(Nameofform As Form2)
        Nameofform.Label1.Text = "Hey This is Form !!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

basically, methods in the Interfaceloader class are doing exact same tasks. However, it handles label from different form.

I was thinking "Object" type param might work but it gave error

I am not sure how to make one method to handle multiple form event. :(

Is there any ways to make one method to handle both form event individually ?

Comment: if you have 2 forms doing much the same thing, why are they 2 different forms?

Comment: @Plutonix thanks for your question. This is just example. However, when I was building school project,  each setting part has exact same behavior (But not every event in each form) but it is working by different method. (like loading some data to form.). Therefore, I just want to make one methods which each form can share form event..

Comment: Declare an interface, have both form classes implement it.  Now you need only one Change_Label() method.

Comment: @HansPassant yep I was thinking about interface as well. However, interface also require to pass parameter to trigger form event.... I honestly doesn't how to do it..

Comment: What @HansPassant was eluding to - if both form implement this interface they must, by contract, implement the method defined in the interface. That being said, you will have a method in each form - set the values in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that what you posted is just an example, so the best solution will depend on what you actually need to do. However, a simpler way of doing what you posted would be to pass the Label to a single Change_Label method.

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim IFL As New InterfaceLoader
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        IFL.Change_Label(me.Label1)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class Form2
    Dim IFL As New InterfaceLoader
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        IFL.Change_Label(me.Label1)
    End Sub
End Class

Public Class InterfaceLoader
    Public Sub Change_Label(theLabel As Label)
        theLabel.Text = "Hey This is Form !!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Note that this works because the type of the argument passed from both `Button.Click` events is the same (i.e. `Label`).

If you have several forms that have the same characteristics, another possible approach would be to create base class (let's call it `MyForm`) that inherits from `Form` and includes all those common characteristics. Now you can have all your forms inherit from `MyForm` instead of from `Form`, and your `InterfaceLoader` class can have methods that take arguments of type `MyForm`. Even better, the methods you have in `InterfaceLoader` could instead be methods of `MyForm`. For information on inheriting from `Form`, you can read [Windows Forms Visual Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bx1155fz(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: yep, this is example. When I was working on project, i kept thinking about way to simplify all the code. I was thinking about interface and abstract class but i couldn't find proper methods... Is there any resource which I can study this kind of VB.NET method ? thank :)

Comment: @NBB: I edited my answer to include a link to the MSDN documentation that covers inheriting from `Form`.

Answer (score 0):

You using reference to the another control(`Me.Label1`) inside of `Click` event handler of the button.
In that case event handler which can be used for all forms and buttons need to know about that label control.
Use `.Tag` property of the `Button` for referencing a `Label`

```
Public Class InterfaceLoader

    Public Shared Sub Button_ClickChangeLabel(sender as Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim btn As Button = TryCast(sender, Button)
        If btn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Dim mylabel As Label = TryCast(btn.Tag, Label)
        If mylabel Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        mylabel.Text = "This is Form"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Then in every form constructors add next line to wire handler to the control

```
Me.YourButton.Tag = Me.Label1
AddHandler Me.Button1.Click, AddressOf InterfaceLoader.Button_ClickChangeLabel
```

But if logic of the process can be keep inside Form, then I didn't see a reason why you need to use outside classes.
If same behavior used in different forms, then create a base class for it

Comment: thanks for helping me is there any resource which i can study for these kind of idea ? thanks :)